# What is the impurity of a sklearn regressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

Some regressors such as `DecisionTreeRegressor` have the parameter `min_impurity_decrease`, but I cannot find any documentation as to what is meant with impurity. Is the impurity the same as the `criterion` parameter? So when I set `criterion='mae'`, is the mean average error also used in the impurity formula?

Thanks!

Comment: [scikit-learn Tree Mathematical Formulation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#mathematical-formulation) and [DecisionTreeRegressor class documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I looked into both and neither states what the impurity for *regression* is. The first source just states what the criterion can be, but not whether it is used as the impurity in `min_impurity_decrease`.

Comment: "min_impurity_decrease: float, default=0.0 A node will be split if this split induces a decrease of the impurity greater than or equal to this value. ..." ?

Comment: Thanks again, but I already knew the entire time what the term min_impurity_decrease is. However, aiming for a better understanding of the entire picture, I would like to know if there is a meaningful definition of the term "impurity" itself. So independently of the above parameter, what is meant by "impurity" in the context of regression.